# Number of non negative integer solutions of $5a +4b +3c +2d + e=20$.If $a,b, c, d ,e$ are positive integers.

Tags: combinatorics

I thought of taking $5a$ to be a variable. The variable would become greater than equal to $5$. Similarly for the others. But couldn't ensure a remaining an integer on using number of non negative integral solutions formula.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, unles you want non-negative or positive integer solutions...

Answer (score 0):

It is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of the function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+(1%2F((1-x)(1-x%5E2)(1-x%5E3)(1-x%5E4)(1-x%5E5)))

Its value is $\color{red}{192}$.

This is the answer for non-negative values. Read the question! ... they want positive values ... so

It is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of the function
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^{15}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)} 
\end{eqnarray*}
which is $\color{red}{7}$.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Consider $1+1+\cdots+1+2+\cdots+2+\cdots+5+\cdots+5=20$  with $e$ 1's,$d$ 2's etc .. The 1's are represented by $\frac{1}{(1-x)}$ etc ...

Comment: Any other method?

Comment: I think you have solved the problem for solutions in non-negative integers rather than positive integers as requested in the OP.

Comment: @awkward I am sure you don't mean to be awkward (Sorry could not resist the pun !) ... you are absolutely correct ... I have amended my answer & I am very grateful to you for pointing this out.